# Bigcommerce PUT (Inventory Level) using PHP / CURL - ERROR 415 Input content type is not valid

Tags: php, curl, bigcommerce

Morning All,

I am trying to update a SKU's Inventory Level.
I am using this URL... (with my store)

```
https://mystore.mybigcommerce.com/api/v2/products/76/skus/3.json
```

This works (if i go here and enter credentials I can see the GET data about this SKU.

Now the information about updating inventory level is @
http://developer.bigcommerce.com/docs/api/v2/resources/products/skus#PUT.products.id.skus.id.json

Now my code is as follows...

```
//Data to Update 
$StockdataRAW = array('inventory_level' => 1230);
//Data to update (JSON encoded)
$Stockdata = json_encode($StockdataRAW);
//See the JSON String
var_dump($Stockdata);

$api_url = $BC_Api_Path.'/products/76/skus/3.json';
//Display URL created to test 
echo '<a href="'.$api_url.'">'.$api_url.'</a>';

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $api_url ); 
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array ('Accept: application/json', 'Content-        Length: 0') );                                   
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT'); 
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0 ); 
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD,  $BC_Api_User.":".$BC_Api_Token ); 
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0 );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 ); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $Stockdata);  
$response = curl_exec( $ch );   

//Just a dump of the response
echo'<pre>';
var_dump($response);
echo'</pre><hr>';

//decode the JSON
$result = json_decode($response); 
print_r($result);
```

I have also tried amending this line...

```
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $Stockdata);
```

To...

```
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $StockdataRAW);
```

&

```
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($StockdataRAW));
```

&

```
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($Stockdata));
```

The error I get in my VAR_DUMP Response IS....

```
string '[{"status":415,"message":"The specified input content type is not valid."}]' (length=75)
```

What Am i doing wrong? I can't figure this out!
Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried

```
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: application/json', 'Accept: application/json', 'Content-Length: 0'));
```

Also the changing the Content-Length to something other than 0.

Comment: Hi Lisa, Thanks for that. Seems to have helped but I am now getting this error returned.

    `string '[{"status":400,"message":"A body is required for this request but was not supplied."}]' (length=86)`

Comment: If i amend the Content-Length to 50 for instance I get... `boolean false` returned

Comment: RESOLVED! Used your Code but removed the content bit altogether and is now working a treat!